# Elmah error filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I've configured an error filter in my Web.config file like the one below. The website is an ASP.NET MVC4 one and we have custom error pages (views) for 404 and 403 errors. The issue I am experiencing is the following: running the website locally in both DEBUG & RELEASE mode I can successfully see the custom 404 error page, while online the Windows Server error page is displayed. Why?

```
<elmah>
   <errorFilter>
     <test>
       <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
     </test>
   </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```